Attribute error when trying to load an image using the pillow library
I am doing an exercise in my Python course using the Pillow library, in my course they are asking me to use the Pillow library so that I can take a print of the image, load and save the image, but it is giving this attribute error, could it be Was there some update to the library that ended up removing this function?
in <module>
    screenshot.show("Teste.png")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'PIL.ImageGrab' has no attribute 'show'

I looked in the documentation but image.show is still there... Do I have to download any additional packages?
I looked at the documentation, searched the internet and there was nothing about...

show more code so that we can reproduce it

Please click [edit] and make a proper [mcve].

how do you create screenshot ? I expect that you did screenshot = ImageGrab but it has to be screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()

I guess that you do
screenshot = ImageGrab

because when I use this then screenshot.show() shows me you error.
But it has to be
screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()


Well worked out
